# multithreaded application & mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm planning on a multithreaded application to get 1 row from MySQL, process data & save it.
processing data takes about 10 seconds for each row & there are millions of rows and growing.

I want to select row & update `status` column to prevent other threads to access the row.
But, in this short time that two queries are executing, other threads can access the row and using a multiquery or row locking cant prevent them.

How can i lock a row that other threads don't access to read that? Is it possible in MySQL? if not, which Database can I use instead?

Comment: MySQL will let you do row level locking.  But your application will have to be careful, because other threads that are trying to access that same row will simply wait, or throw errors.

Comment: Thanks Brian, but how can I select the next instead? as I said, there is millions of rows and each process takes about 10 seconds. waiting threats for 10 second is not wisely for this application at all.

Comment: You do not need to lock the row for 10 seconds, only for the microsecond it takes to update a column to say a thread has taken that row, so other threads do not select it as well.

Comment: You are right, Dan. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL Reference Manual :: SELECT .. FOR UPDATE and SELECT .. LOCK IN SHARE MODE Locking Reads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

Comment: Thanks Dan, I'll check that document.

Comment: If you're still around, please click the checkmark icon next to the answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I'm not registered user & I can't do that, sorry.

Comment: Shila, yes you can. There is no such thing as registration here. You're logged in, that's why you can ask a question and write that comment. It's the big checkmark graphic under the voting arrows on the left.